# RIGHT() function in Postgres is not right

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-function

I'm reviewing the [Postgres RIGHT() function documentation](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-right/), right..

For the documentation example:

```
SELECT RIGHT('XYZ', 2);
```

I was expecting the right response as per the documentation viz;

```
 right
-------
 YZ
(1 row)
```

But then I ran the query in Aginity Workbench and the result wasn't right. I get:

```
found "RIGHT" (at char 8) expecting an identifier found a keyword
```

Can someone set me right?

Comment: I love the the actual question title :)

Comment: Nitpicking: that link is not "the Postgres documentation. The official Postgres manual is here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html

Comment: What does `select version()` show you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `right` function is only available beginning with Postgres version 9.1.  I am guessing that the version used which generated that error message is using version 9.0 or earlier.

See the [documentation for 9.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html) which does not have a `right` function, then see the [documentation for 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) which shows that `right` is available.

As a workaround, you may use `substr`:

```
select
    substr('Hello World', char_length('Hello World') - 4, 5);

World
```

Comment: If it is version I might nag about not falling too far behind on versions. I think around ver 9.6 "create table if not exists" was added which I find so useful. Upgrading is so easy and often saves a lot of grief